# SPFx - How to get current list Title in WebPart

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-webparts

I add my sharepoint framework webpart in AddForm.aspx page in my list. I want to get current list title.
[image]
How to do this?

When i use **_spPageContextInfo** i have following properties for list:

[image]

Comment: can you check with `this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext.listTitle` ?

Comment: not working :( Cannot find a property listTitle

Comment: hmm, can you try it as `let listTitle: string = (<any>window)._spPageContextInfo.listTitle;` first in your render method and then assign it your addform property ?

Comment: i'll try with this...

Comment: See my updated question...

Comment: how about `let listId: string = (<any>window)._spPageContextInfo.pageListId;` then ? It seems the `listTitle` is not available in 2016 onPrem pagecontext object

Comment: This working for me :)

Comment: Cool , have added it as an answer. Request you to please accept it. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like list title value is not present in the `_spPageContextInfo` object in SP 2016 OnPrem.

Also, looks like on the classic page `AddForm.aspx`, the `this.context.pageContext` is undefined.

So, as a workaround, you can make you of the classic `_spPageContextInfo` object's `pageListId` value. This will give you the list id using which you can make the REST API call

To use it in your webpart, you can use the below code:

```
 let listId: string = (<any>window)._spPageContextInfo.pageListId;
```

And use it somewhat as below;

```
var restUrl: string = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + 
                      "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'" + listId + "')/items";

this.context.spHttpClient.get(restUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => { 
...your code
```